# CSS Why does my animation do a unwanted pixel jump?

Tags: javascript, html, css, sass

When I hover on my tile, my animation is correct, but when I do the opposite of hover (dehover/unhover?) my animation do just work to 50%

[image: home button]

1. normal state, like picture
2. hover, bachground tile rotate to 45deg, house stands still (rotate -45deg)
3. unhover: bachground tiles rotates smoothly back, house stays in position. When the animation ends, the house jumps 1-2 px to the left.

it triggers me harder as it should

HTML/JSX

```
<div className="end__tile">
          <Link to="/">
            <ImHome className="end__icon" size={50} />
          </Link>
        </div>
```

SCSS:

```css
.end {
  &__container {
    ...
  }
  &__icon {
    color: $text;
    transition: 500ms;
  }
  &__tile {
    background-color: $background;
    width: 4em;
    height: 4em;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    border-radius: 10px;
    transition: 500ms;

    &:hover {
      transform: rotate(45deg) scale(1.2);
      transition: 500ms;
      background-color: $detail;
    }
    &:hover .end__icon {
      transform: rotate(-45deg);
      transition: 500ms;
      color: $accent;
    }
    &:active {
      transform: rotate(180deg) scale(0.9);
      transition: 500ms;
      background-color: $text;
    }
    &:active .end__icon {
      transform: rotate(-180deg);
      transition: 500ms;
      color: $background;
    }
  }
}
```

why does it a jump? One other icon jumps down and at the last one, the tile jumps one to the right. Why?